# Function to remove a part of a string before a capital letter in Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I have a dataframe that includes a column ['locality_name'] with names of villages, towns, cities. Some names are written like "town of Hamilton", some like "Hamilton", some like "city of Hamilton" etc. As such, it's hard to count unique values etc. My goal is to leave the names only.

I want to write a function that removes the part of a string till the capital letter and then apply it to my dataframe.

That's what I tried:

import re

def my_slicer(row):
"""
Returns a string with the name of locality
"""
return re.sub('ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTVXYZ','', row['locality_name'])

raw_data['locality_name_only'] = raw_data.apply(my_slicer, axis=1)

I excpected it to return a new column with the names of places. Instead, nothing changed - ['locality_name_only'] has the same values as in ['locality_name'].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`pandas.Series.str.extract`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). For the example :

```
ser = pd.Series(["town of Hamilton", "Hamilton", "city of Hamilton"])
ser_2= ser.str.extract("([A-Z][a-z]+-?\w+)")
```

In your case, use :

```
raw_data['locality_name_only'] = raw_data['locality_name'].str.extract("([A-Z][a-z]+-?\w+)")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(ser_2)

          0
0  Hamilton
1  Hamilton
2  Hamilton
```

Comment: Yeah, that works like a charm! Though it turns Saint-Petersburg into Saint. But I guess there is a way to include hyphens into the result string?

Comment: Yes, you can make the hyphen optional. I updated the regex/answer.

Comment: Many thanks! Works exactly like I wanted without any additional functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `str.replace` and phrase the problem as removing all non uppercase words:

```py
raw_data["locality_name_only"] = df["locality_name"].str.replace(r'\s*\b[a-z]\w*\s*', ' ', regex=True).str.strip()
```